# How to read_excel() in r with the file opened in MS excel? [Evaluation error: zip file 'data.xlsx' cannot be opened.]

Tags: r, excel

The read_excel() function works fine if I close the file in MS Excel, but if the file is opened, the error message pops up:

> Error: Evaluation error: zip file 'plot_Regional comparison_cum2.xlsx'
> cannot be opened.

I used to read excel fine with my excel file open so I would like to know if there's a way to fix this. Some suggestions said the file restriction in MS can be modified, but not sure how to do that.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: Note that you cannot read in a file if it is open for editing. Make sure first that you do not have it open.

Comment: Emm... Thanks for your reply, Phil. But editing or adding a new sheet in the input excel while coding can make the work much easier, I did that before with Rstudio, so I wonder if there's a way to read_excel + edit data in MS excel. Any suggestion to do that would be very much appreciated!! Thanks: )

Comment: Sorry Eleanor, I can't control the behaviour of `readxl::read_excel()`. Maybe consider having a working copy, and save to another filename that then gets used to read into R.